# Changing python file permission with chmod +x

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a definite Python newbie, so the answer here may be obvious. But I'm trying to change a simple .py file's permissions so it can be run directly from the Terminal window (I'm running Python3 from a Macbook). I've entered the shebang line `#! /usr/bin/env python3` at the top of my script, but according to the tutorial I'm following, I next need to run the following command:

```
chmod +x pythonScript.py
```

But every time I try running this either from Terminal or the Python shell, I get the following syntax error:

```
>>> chmod +x pythonScript.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    chmod +x pythonScript.py
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing? How do I change the file permission so I can execute a file directly from the Terminal window?

Comment: what's the syntax error? show us the long listing of the file: "ls -las *.py" without the quotes. also try using the octal: chmod 755 pythonScript.py

Comment: For the record, you're supposed to run from the terminal, not the Python shell.

Comment: You could also run `python pythonScript.py` or `python3 pythonScript.py` from the terminal.

Comment: Here's what it looks like if I run the script from Terminal.  `>>> python3 Fivetimes.py  
  File "<stdin>", line 1  
    python3 Fivetimes.py  
                    ^  
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @Will, with your last comment, it looks like you're running your python script and not the chmod command. can you update your question with some more complete copy/pastes of what you're typing and the output you're seeing? we need more context.

Answer (score 2):

You probably already figured it out but just in case there are others with a similar question.

1. Your .py file should be saved to your home folder. Say my file is `name.py`.
2. When you open the terminal (with current working directory of your home folder) type the command `chmod +x name.py`.
3. Now you will be able to run the file in the terminal by typing `./name.py`

only use `pythonScript.py` if that is the name of your `.py` file

Comment: `home folder as the ./ calls on this`. Nope. `./` refers to the current directory.

Comment: true, I am a newbie myself, and just got a bit carried away on the answer

Answer (score 0):

You should run chmod +x filename and ./filename not in python env(>>>). But in directory